# App_GlobalResources not detected on production server

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have a asp.net web application project, with some global resources.
If i deploy to my dev machine, the resources are used correctly, however in the production server the text appears in the default language so the global resources are not being read.

Any ideas? (i copied the App_GlobalResources directory to the production web dir root)

Comment: Could you give me a little more details? Your application manage multiple languages using resources?

Comment: Hi Claudio, I created global resources to translate the text for a scheduler component we are using (to spanish). When i open the app from my dev machine, it actually shows the new texts defined in the global resources, but in the production server, the default texts (in english) are being shown, so i guess there is a problem , but i don't know where to look. ( If is usefull,i  just xcopy the web folder to the server)

Answer (score 0):

Dear Hugo, App_GlobalResources contains globalresources which inherit from currentculture so if you have 1 - 2 or more languages you have to create a different global resources for each of them. for example

```
CommonResource.en-US.resx

CommonResource.fa-IR.resx

CommonResource.-----.resx
```